# Looking for multilingual wedding website template

Tags: html, github, jekyll

I am looking for a fitting template for a multilingual wedding website. Ideally, it would be available in two/ three languages. The main role of the website is to provide an easy way for guests to RSVP and for us to have an overview of those who did RSVP. I don't mind whether it's a one or multiple page setup. I typically work with Hugo or Jekyll using GitHub pages, so ideally I would prefer a template with that workflow.

Thanks in advance!